# Error when loading UIAlertController

Tags: swift2, ios9, uialertcontroller

I want to load an alert when internet connection is not available. The function for checking internet connection is ready but I cannot load the alert. So I just put the alert code in viewDidLoad without any conditions etc. and got this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController: 0x12752d400 on x.ViewController: 0x127646f00 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Delegates
        verificationCode.delegate = self

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"This feature isn't available right now", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in }
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {}


        if (!Util.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
            self.isConnected = false
        }
    }
```

Could you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what has gone wrong.

You are trying to present a view controller in `viewDidLoad` except the view, although loaded, is not in any hierarchy. Try putting the code in the `viewDidAppear` method, which is called after the view appears on screen, and is in a view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 Update**
I think this could help you for your problem :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    verificationCode.delegate = self

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"This feature isn't available right now", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (_) in }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(delete)

    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as UIView
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if (!Util.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
        self.isConnected = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to viewDidAppear from viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Delegates
    verificationCode.delegate = self

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"This feature isn't available right now", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in }
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {}


    if (!Util.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
        self.isConnected = false
    }


}
```